# Using multiple files for fetching events in jQuery FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, symfony, fullcalendar

I am implementing jQuery FullCalendar in my Symfony2 site but I need to be able to show events from two different sources, and highlight them in different colours so the front end user can differentiate between each type.

Currently, I am using this code in my calendar settings js to fetch events from a json file:

```
events:
   {
     url: 'calendarjson/events.json'
   },
```

Here is my events.json file, if it is any help:

> [{"id":1,"title":"To Do","description":"Edited To Do text!View call log</a>","start":"2015-10-30
>   14:30:00","allDay":0},{"id":2,"title":"Test
>   Reminder","description":"asfsafasfd","start":"2015-11-10
>   12:00:00","allDay":0}]

However, I need to be able to fetch data from another file which contains driver sheets for a removal company, so users can see what is coming up.

Is there a way to allow the calendar to use two different json files to grab events from and, preferably, implement different colours for the background of the event?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From API:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    eventSources: [

        // your event source
        {
            url: '/myfeed.php', // use the `url` property
            color: 'yellow',    // an option!
            textColor: 'black'  // an option!
        },
        {
            url: '/myfeed2.php', // use the `url` property
            color: 'yellow',    // an option!
            textColor: 'black'  // an option!
        }

        // any other sources...

    ]

});
```

http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/